# Django form: call 'clean' before 'clean_<form_field>'

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, django-2.0

Hi I have a django form in which I have a radio button and several character fields. As part of this form validation I want to clean each of these inputs, and then do some extra cleaning (i.e further cleaning of downstream data).

However, when i put my 'extra cleaning' in clean() this is called after each of the clean_() methods.

Is there a way I can call clean() last?

form.py

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    year = forms.IntegerField(label='Year:', required=True)
    number = forms.IntegerField(label='Number:', required=True)
    stored = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label='Storage:',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=(('Routine', 'Routine',), ('Archive', 'Archive',))
        )


    def clean_year(self):

        self.year = self.cleaned_data['year']

        year_check = re.compile("\d{4}$")

        if year_check.match(str(self.year)):
            return(self.year)

        else:
            msg = "Year '%s' is incorrect." %(str(self.year))
            logger.error(msg)
            raise(forms.ValidationError(msg))


    def clean_number(self):

        self.number = self.cleaned_data['number']
        number_check = re.compile("\d{1,2}$")

        if number_check.match(str(self.number)):
            return(self.number)

        else:
            msg = "Year '%s' is incorrect." %(str(self.number))
            logger.error(msg)
            raise(forms.ValidationError(msg))


def clean_stored(self):
    try:
        self.stored = self.cleaned_data['stored']

    except:
        self.stored = False


def clean(self):

     self.more_cleaning_methods()


def more_cleaning_methods():

     print(self.stored)
```

This results in an error if stored radio button is not checked - instead of raising a form error. This is because clean() is called first - and therefore my class object does not have an "`attribute 'stored'`"

is there a way I can call clean() after individually cleaning the field inputs, or is there another way to call a clean method (before form.is_valid() == True) after my field inputs?

Thanks

Comment: No, clean() is not called first, it is called last - as is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: this is very confusing to me then - why would this error occur?
As clean() is called last - self.stored is defined. So the error "form object has no attribute 'stored'" should not happen...

Comment: `self.stored` is only defined if `clean_stored` is called at all. Which it isn't if no data is received for the `stored` field. I must say though, I can't really see why you're doing any of this, rather than just accessing the value of `self.cleaned_data['stored']` directly in the `clean()` or `more_cleaning_methods()` methods.

Comment: I could do it in clean(), for the sake of consistency with the other inputs I wanted to separate them - i was just confused why having required=True wasn't working - but the clean_stored() method is not being called at all, and then self.stored is being used in clean() - hence attribute error. I will put my try: self.stored = self.cleaned_data['stored'] in clean() now - thanks for your help